# Replace with NA to the right of rightmost row string

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I have a dataframe below. My actual dataset has 800 columns.

For the **rightmost** column containing the string `abc`, I want to make every value in that row to the **right** of that column `NA`.

Here is an example:

```
col1 <- as.Date(c('2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-02-01', '2019-03-01', '09-02-18'))
col2 <- c('jkabc', 'abckee', 'kekdm', 'oeoeo', 'mends')
col3 <- as.Date(c('2019-08-02', '2019-08-01', '2019-08-04', '2019-07-02', '09-03-15'))
col4 <- c('nnnnn', 'kndabc_kd', 'kenabc123', 'werc', 'mendiabc')
col5 <- as.Date(c('2019-12-11', '2019-11-22', '2019-06-12', '2019-09-30', '08-04-18'))
col6 <- c('nnnnn', 'kdekd', 'abc14', 'ekmabckem', 'nekm')

df<-data.frame(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)

df

        col1   col2       col3      col4       col5      col6
1 2019-01-01  jkabc 2019-08-02     nnnnn 2019-12-11     nnnnn
2 2019-01-02 abckee 2019-08-01 kndabc_kd 2019-11-22     kdekd
3 2019-02-01  kekdm 2019-08-04 kenabc123 2019-06-12     abc14
4 2019-03-01  oeoeo 2019-07-02      werc 2019-09-30 ekmabckem
5 0009-02-18  mends 0009-03-15  mendiabc 0008-04-18      nekm
```

There are instances where columns do and do not contain the string `abc` within the value. I want to change it to this:

```
        col1   col2       col3      col4       col5      col6
1 2019-01-01  jkabc         NA        NA         NA        NA
2 2019-01-02 abckee 2019-08-01 kndabc_kd         NA        NA
3 2019-02-01  kekdm 2019-08-04 kenabc123 2019-06-12     abc14
4 2019-03-01  oeoeo 2019-07-02      werc 2019-09-30 ekmabckem
5 0009-02-18  mends 0009-03-15  mendiabc         NA        NA
```

Comment: If only `tidyverse` had a `gather_if` function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very ugly solution.

```
df = data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x){
  index = grep("abc", x)
  index = index[length(index)]
  if(index > 0){
    if(index != length(x))
    x[(index + 1):length(x)] = NA
  }
x
})))
```

Problem here is that you lose the date formatting.

Comment: Thanks, I'm away from my computer now but will check when I get back. Definitely need the dates to stay in it's format though.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a solution that creates a logical matrix of which cells to set to NA and then does so.

```
abc <- grepl("abc", as.matrix(dm))
dim(abc) <- dim(df)
abc <- t(apply(abc, 1, function(x) {
  if (any(x)) {
    min_abc <- min(which(x))
    rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), c(min_abc, length(x) - min_abc))
  } else {
    x
  }
}))
df[abc] <- NA
df
```

Comment: this didn't seem to work for me. I think it was removing the value as well

Comment: @nak5120 sorry I misunderstood the question. This should work now.